# Cannot suppress downloads menu when a download starts in TEdgeBrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi-11-alexandria, tedgebrowser

Since I can no longer call active-X from my client JavaScript as I did with TWebBrowser since 2013, I had to write a work-around.
I have it working except for the Fly-Out menu that Edge throws out.
I have gone into the settings and turned it off.  When I use an Edge directly, that decision is respected but when I call it through the TEdgeBrowser, it always open the Downloads Menu, Asking where I want to save.
My intentions are to have this be an event driven operation with no user interaction.

I've searched the registry and policies, along with ICoreWebView properties.  I did find ICoreWebView2DownloadOperation and ICoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs but Delphi does not expose these in Winapi.WebView2!!!  Nor am I given a WebView2.TLB.  If so, I would import it and create my own wrapper.  From my reading:

Is it possible to modify the Winapi.WebView2 and add the ICoreWebView2DownloadStartingEventArgs interface?

get_Handled and put_Handled
The host may set this flag to TRUE to hide the default download dialog for this download.

public HRESULT get_Handled(BOOL * handled)

The download will progress as normal if it is not canceled, there will just be no default UI shown. By default the value is FALSE and the default download dialog is shown.
The host may set this flag to TRUE to hide the default download dialog for this download.

Sets the Handled property.
public HRESULT put_Handled(BOOL handled)

The download will progress as normal if it is not canceled, there will just be no default UI shown. By default the value is FALSE and the default download dialog is shown.

My little test app:

```
unit MainFormU;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, System.UITypes, System.Types,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Edge, WebView2, Winapi.ActiveX;

type
  TfrmMain = class(TForm)
    MainMenu: TMainMenu;
    EdgeBrowser: TEdgeBrowser;
    RunHTML1: TMenuItem;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure mniScriptClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    MyScript:TStringList;
  end;

var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;


implementation

uses
  System.Math, System.StrUtils, System.Win.ComObj, System.IOUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  MyScript.Free;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EdgeBrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
  MyScript := TStringList.Create;
  MyScript.LoadFromFile('TextToFile.html');
end;

procedure TfrmMain.mniScriptClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EdgeBrowser.NavigateToString(MyScript.Text);
end;

object frmMain: TfrmMain
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Main Form'
  ClientHeight = 264
  ClientWidth = 598
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -13
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu
  Position = poDefault
  OnClose = FormClose
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  TextHeight = 16
  object EdgeBrowser: TEdgeBrowser
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 598
    Height = 262
    Align = alTop
    TabOrder = 0
    TabStop = True
    ExplicitWidth = 633
  end
  object MainMenu: TMainMenu
    Left = 528
    Top = 32
    object mniScript: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Run HTML'
      OnClick = mniScriptClick
      object RunHTML1: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Run HTML'
      end
    end
  end
end

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile('N:34.00C, S:34.00D, E:8400C, W:8359A', 'ShowMinBounds')">Save Text to File</button></td>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

function saveTextAsFile(textToWrite, fileNameToSaveAs)
{
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null)
    {
      downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
        downloadLink.click();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```